# fill array from a dataset c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dataset, sqlclient

I have a dataset with 6 strings. How can I fill a string array with theses strings from the dataset. Id imagine loop throught dataset.
I have a quiz class with question and answers.

heres the code to fill dataset.

```
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "Select * from Questions";

            SqlDataAdapter dataapt = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet questions = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                dataapt.Fill(questions, "Questions");
            }
```

heres my quiz class

```
           public class Quiz
            {
              public string[] questions { get; set; }
              public string[] answers { get; set; }



    public Quiz()
    {
        questions = new string[] { "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth","Fifth","sixth" };
        answers = new string[] { "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "sixth" };
    }
```

is it possible to fill the array from the dataset??

Comment: Yes, it is. Let's try!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be done. Take a look at this example.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Questions");

dt.Rows.Add(new String[] { "One" });
dt.Rows.Add(new String[] { "Two" });
dt.Rows.Add(new String[] { "Three" });
dt.Rows.Add(new String[] { "Four" });
dt.Rows.Add(new String[] { "Five" });

String[] questions = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["Questions"].ToString()).ToArray();
```